# SQL dumping is locking the database and crashing my website

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run MySQLDump without Locking Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables)

My website uses a mysql 5 database with a MyISAM engine.

I would like to use mysqldump to back up the database or create copies of it, but whenever I use it, it locks the database, thus crashing my website..

Any ideas on how to back up my database without causing downtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database relies on any kind of referential integrity, it'll be essential to lock at least parts of it whilst performing a dump. (Otherwise, you'll get snapshots of the various tables at different times, which is likely to cause issues.)

That said, unless you have a very, very large database this shouldn't be a significant issue. (i.e.: It really shouldn't take that long.) How much data is in the database?

Update:

You can use the `--lock-tables=false` mysqldump option, but you need to be aware of the consequences of this as outlined above.