# Copy a huge MySQL table from a remote to a local database

Tags: java, mysql

I have read-only access to a remote MySQL database, which contains a very large table (hundreds of millions of lines).

To get faster access to that table, I want to copy it to my local database.

What is the best way to do this?

"`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`" doesn't work, because I don't have the required permissions on the remote database.

I tried to use Java to `SELECT` all rows `FROM` the remote table, save them to a local text file, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE;` however, the select broke with

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Comment: **define large**, what someone at a mom and pop development shop might consider large might not be what someone at google or facebook consider large.

Comment: Is it possible for you to SELECT INTO OUTFILE '...' into a directory that you have permissions for?

Comment: "define large" - well, as I said, it is large enough so that Java breaks with an "OutOfMemoryError". That is, several hundred million lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mysqldump command on the remote database to extract the SQL statements of the database required. Then copy the extracted file to your local system and execute the sql file which will create the database in the local system.

Here is the mysqldump example
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/mysql/mysqlbackup/mysqldump.html

Comment: OK, but I don't have permission to lock the tables in the remote database, so I have to use this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables

The command I run is: "mysqldump --single-transaction -h [remote-host] -P [remote-port] -u [remote-readonly-username] [remote-database-name] [remote-table-name] | mysql -u[local-username] -p[local-password] [local-database]"

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Synchronization, latest version of PHPMyAdmin provides an option to set synchronization. You need to set source DB as remote database and destination to your local database.
Setting up a PHP (and PHPMyAdmin too) on local machine is not a big task. if table is much bigger you may need to increase maximum execution time for phpmyadmin script.
Alternatively if you can access remote MySQL port then you can try to connect to remote db from your local machine as `mysql -h remote_IP -u usernmae -pPassword`. if it connects then you can definitely use mysqldump command on local machine. check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your Java program is likely to be because the MySQL JDBC driver stores the entire ResultSet in memory by default.  With a huge table, this is highly likely to cause an OutOfMemoryError.

You can stop the MySQL driver from doing this by following the instructions in the ResultSet section of [this page in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) (which I found via [this blog post](http://benjchristensen.com/2008/05/27/mysql-jdbc-memory-usage-on-large-resultset/)).

I was able to reproduce an OutOfMemoryError with a simple Java program that simply read each row out of a table with over 120 million rows.  After making the changes suggested in the MySQL documentation, my Java program completed without any memory issues.