# Sync a huge table of remote database to a table of local database with table containing a field "lastModificationTime"

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Similar looking questions that doesn't answer my question:
[copy data from a mysql database to other mysql database with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557216/copy-data-from-a-mysql-database-to-other-mysql-database-with-java) and
[Copy a huge MySQL table from a remote to a local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147411/copy-a-huge-mysql-table-from-a-remote-to-a-local-database)

**My Problem:** I have a remote mysql database for whom I have only mysql read access, not have access to the server. That is the source database. I have another mysql database for which I have both access to server and mysql. Lets say it target database. Both target database have a table that is duplicate in structure of a table in source database. To make the problem simple, suppose only new data are added to source table. That table have a field named "lastModificationTime" that contains the timestamp of a row last modified(inserted). Based on that field, with a java app, I have to pull rows from source table  that needs to be inserted to target database table to sync them. Initially, target table is empty and source table size is almost 3 GB. This causes problem when my java app tries to select all rows from remote table and gets exception. The exception is java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure:... bla bla ...

*Note: I have used jdbc to connect to both of the database.
*Note: There is also a chance of OutOfMemoryException if "communican link failure" doesn't happen as table size is almost 3GB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In one transaction, try reading in the `COUNT` from the source table, then iterate over the source, processing say 1000 records at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I have made a solution based on your idea. I first read count of rows in source table which have "lastModificationTime" greater than "lastModificationTime" in target table. Then iterate on reading chunks of rows from source table using query like " select ... ... from ... where lastModificationTime> some_value order by lastModificationTime limit a,b " . And then insert those rows in target table. Thanks for your response again.

Answer (score 2):

Given the size of your source table, you will almost certainly need to divide it into manageable chunks.

As your records are timestamped, that should be quite easy. The precise implementation will depend a bit on your timestamp format, and you may need to spend some time analysing the source records to optimize it. For the initial import you can iterate backwards from the current date.

The basic implementation would look something like this:

```
public static void import (){

    int interval = -10; //get records in 10 day blocks
    int returnedRecords = 0;

    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance(); //This will default to now
    Calendar endTime = startTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, interval); // 10 days ago

    do {

        //code here to get records between start and end timestamps
        returnedRecords = ?? // Get the count of any returned records
        startTime = endTime;
        endTime = endTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, interval);

    } while (returnedRecords > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you can simply backup and restore data to your target server. If possible you can try writing a program on the source server to detect if there is change to the table. This program can run in background as Windows Service.

Other way is to write a program which will update the target database when an update transaction takes place in source database.

I have worked on several integration projects which needed similar synchronizations. Its always better to restore the database till date and then carry on the synchronization later. This decreases the overhead and the exceptions while taking care of huge database sync.