# mysqldump not creating create database syntax

Tags: mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup

I am using mysql database. I am using mysqldump to create a dump of my database. I want the database to be dumped such that there is a drop database if exists command followed by create database command. I am using the following command (on my sample database project).

`mysqldump --skip-comments --compact --add-drop-database -uroot -proot project`

I am getting the following result:

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `year` varchar(5) default NULL,
  `branch` varchar(50) default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `names` VALUES ('Venkat','4-1','cse'),('rambabu','4-1','cse'),('nagesh','4-2','cse'),('ganesh','4-2','cse'),('rajesh','3-2','cse'),('ramesh','3-2','cse'),('sasirekha','3-1','cse'),('leela','3-1','cse');
CREATE TABLE `store` (
  `name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `branch` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `year` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `feedback` varchar(500) default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `store` VALUES ('nagesh','CSE','4-2','feedback for nagesh'),('ganesh','CSE','4-2','his performance is good. his behaviour is good.'),('rajesh','CSE','3-2','feedback of rajesh2'),('ramesh','CSE','3-2','feedback of ramesh'),('rajesh','CSE','3-2','feedback of rajesh'),('ramesh','CSE','3-2','feedback of ramesh'),('Venkat','CSE','4-1','feedback of venkat'),('rambabu','CSE','4-1','feedback of rambabu');
```

As you can see, i do not have the drop database and create database syntax here. What am i doing wrong??
MySqlServer ver: 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45

Comment: I hope you use that `-p` switch in only dev machine.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, whats so bad about using the `-p`?

Comment: @vinhboy "that `-p`" is `-proot` which echos password and stays in bash history. Easy finding.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this:
    mysqldump --skip-comments --compact --add-drop-database -uroot -proot **--databases project**

Comment: Some might need the --lock-tables=False option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables