# mysqldump without interrupting live production INSERT

Tags: mysql

I'm about to migrate our production database to another server. It's about 38GB large and it's using MYISAM tables. Due to I have no physical access to the new server file system, we can only use mysqldump.

I have looked through this site and see whether will mysqldump online backup bring down our production website. From this post: [Run MySQLDump without Locking Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables) , it says obviously mysqldump will lock the db and prevent insert. But after a few test, I'm curious to find out it shows otherwise.

If I use

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --flush-logs testDB > /tmp/backup.sql
```

mysqldump will eventually by default do a '**--lock-tables**', and this is a **READ LOCAL** locks ([refer to mysql 5.1 doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables)), where concurrent insert still available. I have done a for loop to insert into one of the table every second while mysqldump take one minute to complete. Every second there will be record inserted during that period. Which mean, mysqldump will not interrupt production server and **INSERT can still go on**.

Is there anyone having different experience ? I want to make sure this before carry on to my production server, so would be glad to know if I have done anything wrong that make my test incorrect.

[My version of mysql-server is 5.1.52, and mysqldump is 10.13]

Comment: You should gain the access to new server **FIRST**, and probably looking mysql replication to solve the migration . **REMEMBER:** You can dump, and install to new server, **BUT** after you dump the data, there will be **MORE** new write, how you going to synchronize the new write to the new server?

Comment: For the subsequent new data write, we will be solving it by using mysqlbinlog, that should be well taken care. Now my main concern will be the first time backup using mysqldump. I just want to make sure whether mysqldump will prevent INSERT or not. From my test, it didn't show it will. Just want to make sure how is other experience.

Answer (score 3):

Now, you may have a database with disjunct tables, or a data warehouse - where everything isn't normalized (at all), and where there are no links what so ever between the tables. In that case, any dump would work.

I ASSUME, that a production database containing 38G data is containing graphics in some form (BLOB's), and then - ubuquitously - you have links from other tables. Right?

Therefore, you are - as far as I can see it - at risk of loosing serious links between tables (usually primary / foreign key pairs), thus, you may capture one table at the point of being updated/inserted into, while its dependant (which uses that table as its primary source) has not been updated, yet. Thus, you will loose the so called integrity of your database.

More often than not, it is extremely cumbersome to restablish integrity, most often due to that the system using/generating/maintaining the database system has not been made as a transaction oriented system, thus, relationships in the database cannot be tracked except via the primary/foreign key relations.

Thus, you may surely get away with copying your table without locks and many of the other proposals here above - but you are at risk of burning your fingers, and depending on, how sensitive the operations are of the system - you may burn yourself severely or just get a surface scratch.

Example: If your database is a critical mission database system, containing recommended heart beat rate for life support devices in an ICU, I would think more than twice, before I make the migration.

If, however, the database contains pictures from facebook or similar site = you may be able to live with the consequences of anything from 0 up to 129,388 lost links :-).

Now - so much for analysis. Solution:

YOU WOULD HAVE to create a software which does the dump for you with full integrity, table-set by table-set, tuple by tuple. You need to identify that cluster of data, which can be copied from your current online 24/7/365 base to your new base, then do that, then mark that it has been copied.

IFFF now changes occur to the records you have already copied, you will need to do subsequent copy of those. It can be a tricky affair to do so.

IFFF you are running a more advanced version of MYSQL - you can actually create another site and/or a replica, or a distributed database - and then get away with it, that way.

IFFF you have a window of lets say 10 minutes, which you can create if you need it, then you can also just COPY the physical files, located on the drive. I am talking about the .stm .std - and so on - files - then you can close down the server for a few minutes, then copy.

Now to a cardinal question:

You need to do maintenance of your machines from time to time. Haven't your system got space for that kind of operations? If not - then what will you do, when the hard disk crashes. Pay attention to the 'when' - not 'if'.

Comment: How does a 38 GB database size imply graphics or BLOB content?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Use of `--opt` is the same as specifying `--add-drop-table`, `--add-locks`, `--create-options`, `--disable-keys`, `--extended-insert`, `--lock-tables`, `--quick`, and `--set-charset`. All of the options that `--opt` stands for also are on by default because `--opt` is on by default.

**2)** mysqldump can retrieve and dump table contents row by row, or it can retrieve the entire content from a table and buffer it in memory before dumping it. Buffering in memory can be a problem if you are dumping large tables. To dump tables row by row, use the `--quick` option (or `--opt`, which enables `--quick`). The `--opt` option (and hence `--quick`) is enabled by default, so to enable memory buffering, use `--skip-quick`.

**3)** `--single-transaction` This option issues a `BEGIN SQL` statement before dumping data from the server (transactional tables `InnoDB`).

If your schema is a combination of both `InnoDB` and `MyISAM` , following example will help you:

```
    mysqldump -uuid -ppwd --skip-opt --single-transaction --max_allowed_packet=512M db > db.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it before but you could try `--skip-add-locks` when dumping.

Though it might take longer, you could dump in several patches, each of which would take very little time to complete. Adding `--skip--add-drop-table` would allow you to upload these multiple smaller dumps into the same table without re-creating it. Using `--extended-insert` would make the sql file smaller to boot.

Possibly try something like `mysqldump -u -p${password} --skip-add-drop-table --extended-insert --where='id between 0 and 20000' test_db test_table > test.sql`. You would need to dump the table structures and upload them first in order to do it this way, or remove the --skip-add-drop-table for the first dump

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice. But at the moment my main concern is not trying to reduce the mysqldump time, as the data is too much. My intention will be to find out, will `mysqldump` prevent INSERT or not while it's running. Looking for anyone that have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump doesn't add --lock-tables by default. Try to use --lock-tables
Let me know if it helped

BTW - you should also use add-locks which will make your import faster!

Comment: hi, I have tested again and it is confirmed that mysqldump by default will issue --lock-tables. Two point to prove that. First, 
`mysqldump --help|grep lock`
will show 'lock-tables' is TRUE.
Second, using
`mysql>show open tables;`
during mysqldump happening, the 'In_use' column will indicate 1, and another mysql INSERT doesn't make it turn to 2, so that show it is a LOCK READ LOCAL.

So my question is, is there anybody else having their mysqldump locking the table and prevent INSERT ? because mine didn't.