# mysqldump blocks inserts on innodb database?

Tags: mysql

When performing the default mysqldump on a innodb database, does it perform table locking and pending "INSERTS" are queued? I have transactional database, and out of 100K+ records, I found maybe 2-3 dozen duplicate records (all fields are the same such as timestamp except for the primary keys).

I suspect the user on the front end application clicked "Save" on the GUI while a database backup is in progress, and then clicks it a few more times until he receives a response. That's my theory.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `mysqldump` locks by default.  Since you are using innodb, use `--single-transaction` to prevent locking (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables)).  Or use something like the [innodb hot backup tool](http://www.innodb.com/wp/products/hot-backup/).

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Does the `--single-transaction` option take any less or more time?

Comment: It might be a bit slower, but probably not much.  Try it and see!

Comment: I just edited cron and added the option. I ran the script. It took maybe twice as long (20 seconds). Db size, a .sql file, is about 73MB.

Comment: Besides slower backup times when using `--single-transaction`, are there any other downsides? What happens when an INSERT is performed while mysqldump is in progress with this option?

Comment: All database operations will complete normally, although they may take a bit longer while the backup is in progress.