# How to speed up php backup script?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, backup, database-backups

I have been using a mysql db backup script in php and the backups take 21 hours my dbs.  I want to use it as a daily backup script through cli and cron and was wondering if you guys could take a look at it and see if there is anyway I can optimize it.

```
<?

//Timer start
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;


ini_set('memory_limit','4000M');
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);


$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

$db = "tagdb";

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$result = mysql_query("show databases like 'tag%'");  // we only want tagdb

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $dbs[] = $row[0];
}

foreach($dbs as $db)
{
        if(strlen($db) == 10 || $db == "tagdb" || $db == "tagui")
        {
        echo $db."\n";
                backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    }
}


//backup_tables($host,$username,$password,$db);

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

      $fname = 'db-backup-'.$name.'_'.time().'.sql'; 
      echo $fname."\n";
      $handle = fopen($fname,'w+');
      $return = '';
      fwrite($handle,$return);
      fclose($handle);

      $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
      mysql_select_db($name,$link);

      //get all of the tables
      if($tables == '*')
{
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = @mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
}
else
{
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
}

foreach($tables as $table)
{
  $handle = fopen($fname,'a');
  fwrite( $handle, 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';' );

  $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
  fwrite( $handle, "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n" );

  $offset = 10000;

  $start = 0;
  do {
      $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM ".$table." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$offset."" );
      $start += $offset;


      $num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $result );
      if (false === $result) {
        //close original file
        fclose($handle);
        //open error file
        $errfn = $fname.'.ERROR';
        $errf = fopen($errfn,'a');
        $err = mysql_error();
        fwrite( $errf, $err );
        fclose($errf);
        //reopen original file
        $handle = fopen($fname,'a');
        //break loop
        $num_rows = 0;
      }

      while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) ) {
          $line = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
          foreach( $row as $value ) {
              $value = addslashes( $value );
              @$value = ereg_replace( "\n","\\n", $value );
              $line .= '"'.$value.'",';
          }
          $line = substr( $line, 0, -1 ); // cut the final ','
          $line .= ");\n";
          fwrite( $handle, $line );
      }
  } while( $num_rows !== 0 );
  }

  $return="\n\n\n";
  fwrite($handle,$return);
  fclose($handle);
}

//End timer and output time
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo "\n Page generated in ".$total_time." seconds. \n";
?>
```

I was thinking about splitting the backups into parallel processes but my databases are huge and I'm not sure if php will run out of memory because it has before.
Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

ps. I know there are better ways to do a backup but this particular script works well for me as the other options, such as mysqldump is not available to me.

Comment: please use mysqldump; that script is wrong in so many ways.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: How is mysqldump not available to you? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Dagon lol yeah i know. but like i said i cant use mysqldump. but this isnt my permanent solution to backups. will get new machines and migrate my db to a linux box where i can use lvm

Comment: @Matt I will look into it thanks, hopefully i can just change all the mysql tags to mysqli/PDO? and im using myisam databases b/c innodb would have to be licensed for me to use.  and i need a hotcopy function since people world wide use the databases. mysqldump locks the dbs and if i turn off the locks im afraid that the backups will be corrupt if someone is editing it during backup.  Although i know this isnt an ideal process either.  one of the few scripts i found online that works and that i understand since i only program in php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables would imply that using a mysqldump with the `--single-transaction` flag, is pretty much what you SHOULD be looking at

Comment: `--lock-tables=false` is better

Comment: At the very least you should use a tool like PHPmyadmin where it has a "make backups" button. `mysqldump` is the only free, reliable way to make MySQL snapshots that actually serve the purpose of providing a data back-up option. If you don't have `mysqldump`, either fix that or use a provider that supports it. Not having access to that is crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you could directly copy a table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

It will be way faster, and you could also have your table on 2 separated database (NEW_DB & OLD_DB)

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_DB.new_table LIKE OLD_DB.old_table;
INSERT NEW_DB.new_table SELECT * FROM OLD_DB.old_table;
```

So you could do it from PHP, WITHOUT transferring data to PHP, with a huge gain in performance.

Comment: I dont quite follow. so basically im creating a temporary table from where I can run the script from? but if I do, the process would take the same amount of time wouldn't it?  i have a few huge databases that are around 1-2gb in a mysqldump of just text so copying a database would take a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to back up your database, just use `mysqldump` as Dagon mentioned. Call it from a cron task on a schedule. Then if you need to roll back, you can simply find proper dump (stored in a .sql file) and execute the file.

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] db_name > [timestamped_filename].sql
```

[Read this article for more information](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/backing-up-mysql-with-mysqldump/).

Comment: was utilizing mysqldump but realized that it was driving productivity down because of locks on myisam dbs and the backups were unsuable if i just removed the locks and continued backing up the dbs while they were in use. thats why i need something like a hotcopy backup for the myisam dbs.

Answer (score 0):

> was utilizing mysqldump but realized that it was driving productivity
>   down because of locks on myisam dbs and the backups were unsuable if i
>   just removed the locks and continued backing up the dbs while they
>   were in use. thats why i need something like a hotcopy backup for the
>   myisam dbs

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your script does no locking at all. If it takes 21 hours to execute, then you've *got* to have synchronization issues.

If you can't use `mysqldump`, the only practical solutions I see are to use a MySQL slave (see: http://www.redips.net/mysql/add-new-slave/ - points 1 and 2 are what interests you) and `mysqlhotcopy`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html .

The first solution is more complicated to set up, but it's probably cleaner and simpler (also, I think, faster) to run. And with a little more set-up, it can double as load-balancing on the SQL server.

Comment: my original script was utilizing mysqldump and locks, this is another script that doesn't lock and outputs and backup i can use. A slave doesnt work for me neither because we have so many concurrent users we have to use temp tables and that outputs alot of errors with the slave replication(if thats what you mean by slave). and mysqlhotcopy is only usable by innodb, which has to be licensed for me to use, hotcopy would just function like dump and lock the dbs for myisam dbs, which i am using right now.

Comment: I will be migrating to linux after i get new servers, and will be utilizing lvm, but thats a few months from now, thats why I needed help optimizing this script as it is a short term thing/temporary backup solution. Thanks for your input though, I will be looking into synchronization.