# MySql table lock while using MySqlDump remotely?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php script to backup my sql databases remotely that utilizes mysqldump.  http://www.dagondesign.com/files/backup_dbs.txt

and I tried to add the the --lock-tables=false since I'm using MyISAM tables but still got an error.

```
exec( "$MYSQL_PATH/mysqldump --lock-tables=false $db_auth --opt $db 2>&1 >$BACKUP_TEMP/$db.sql", $output, $res);
```

error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `advisory_info`': Can't create/write to file 'E:\tmp\#sql_59c_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17) (1)
```

Someone told me this file was the lock file it self and I was able to find it in my Server that I wanted to backup.

So is this the lock file?  And does it lock the database if you do remotely no matter if I put the variable --lock-tables=false? Or should it not be there since there are a lot of people working on the server and someone might have created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7 using Wamp, the option is `--skip-lock-tables`

Took from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726820/731138)

Answer (score 2):

It's likely `--lock-tables=false` isn't doing what you think it's doing. Since you're passing `--lock-tables`, it's probably assuming you *do* want to lock the tables (even though this is the default), so it's locking them. In Linux, we don't prevent flags but appending something like `=false` or `=0`, but normally by having a `--skip-X` or `--no-X`.

You might want to try `--skip-opt`:

```
  --skip-opt          Disable --opt. Disables --add-drop-table, --add-locks,
                      --lock-tables, --set-charset, and --disable-keys.
```

Because `--opt` is enabled by default, you can `--skip-opt` then add back any flags you want.