# mysqldump increase apache process threads?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, apache

We are running into problem with number of apache processes drastically increasing at a specific time. On further investigating, it's found that "mysqldump" was running in MySQL server during that time.

We noticed that while mysqldump was running, the count of apache instances(processes) shoots up to the max. Since we limited MaxClients to 150 there is no further increase in process thread.

My question is: Is it possible that mysqldump would increase number of processes in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLdump itself does not cause Apache to do anything.  MySQLdump and Apache Server are only related in that since they are running on the same machine they are sharing the resources of that machine.

I suspect that when you run MySQLdump your server becomes resource-constrained (could be CPU, Network or Disk). When Apache is resource-constrained an individual Apache process is not able to complete as quickly and move on to the next request so instead new processes are spawned.

Comment: Apache & MySQL are running in different servers. During high process count, Disk IO for MySQL shown > 85%. 

Please note: The application is built with Drupal.

Comment: OK, well the answer is much the same.  MySQLdump is tying up resources on the MySQL server, when Apache asks for something the MySQL server takes longer than usual to respond so the Apache processes pile up while waiting for MySQL to get around to replying.

Comment: Also, MySQLdump may be locking tables. See more on some options for handling this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables