# mySQL simple SELECT failing for all observed values

Tags: mysql

No matter what email address I copy from browsing the 17000+ records in this table I get "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."

I discovered this issue when attempting a join.  Schema is

```
CREATE TABLE `actives` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM `actives` WHERE TRIM(`email`) = 'bar@foo.com';
```

Can anyone suggest an issue that can explain this?  I can see the values when I browse the table with

```
SELECT `email` FROM `actives` LIMIT 0, 30
```

Per comment also tried these:

```
mysql> SELECT `email` FROM `actives` WHERE TRIM(`email`) = TRIM('barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu');
Empty set (0.45 sec)

SELECT `email` FROM `actives` WHERE `email` RLIKE 'barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu';
+-----------------------------+
| email                       |
+-----------------------------+
 |barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu
+-----------------------------+
```

Also this gets 0 rows affected

```
UPDATE `actives` SET `email` = TRIM(`email`)
```

Per request adding mysqldump output with carraige return character at end of email address...

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.28, for FreeBSD9.1 (i386)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: foo
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.28-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `actives`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actives`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `actives` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=310410 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='delete this, useless now';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `actives`
--
-- WHERE:  true limit 1

LOCK TABLES `actives` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actives` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `actives` VALUES (1,0,'barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu\r');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actives` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-04-04 10:32:07
```

Comment: 100% of the times something like this is asked, it's the frontend. Have you tried `SELECT * FROM actives WHERE TRIM(email) = TRIM('bar@foo.com');` to rule out, that invisible characters also are in the clipboard (since you copy&paste). Have you tried with the command line client?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'm sure you are correct but unsure how to proceed.  Added more examples to post now.  Using TRIM() on both gets no results but email RLIKE on domain and whole address gets results.  But using TRIM() to update table does not alter rows.

Comment: The newly added queries were from command line btw

Comment: Then I'd like to try it myself. Can you do `mysqldump -uuser -ppassword dbname tablename --where="true limit 1" >dumpfile` and paste the dumpfile here? It will only dump one row of the table.

Comment: Hmm, getting Access Denied "when doing LOCK TABLES"

Comment: Would select into outfile do?

Comment: Try with `--single-transaction`, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables

Comment: OK, added and I see the carriage return \r at end of email but if TRIM can't remove what is my query to clean that up?

Comment: OK, this worked `UPDATE actives SET email = REPLACE(REPLACE(email, '\r', ''), '\n', '');`

Comment: Want to migrate your comments to an answer?  Thank you very much for your help; will remember mysqldump for debugging this in future

Comment: Did so, including another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments above:

You can use `mysqldump` to see exactly what's stored in the column, including carriage returns and newlines.

Another way to remove those would be to use

```
UPDATE actives SET email = TRIM(BOTH '\r\n' FROM email);
```

Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!!  I never realized mySQL monitor would not show the returns but mysqldump would!  Big help going forward!

Comment: Wow!  TRIM is way more versatile and powerful than I realized!  I normally just use it for whitespace cleaning.  Thanks!

Comment: I've come back to page three times and had to re-check your answer as the one.  SO acting strangely.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the '/r' at the end of the Email. Try this:

```
SELECT `email` FROM `actives` WHERE `email` LIKE 'barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu%';
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No thinking, you got it real correct. A +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

As per your posted dump; the only problem here is `\r` in the email value in your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO `actives` VALUES (1,0,'barfoo@coyote.csusb.edu\r');
                                                           -- Here
```

remove this `\r` and you are all good.

Check this successful fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/131cff/2