# Mysql database backup

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-backups

we have a mysql table which consist of 300 million rows. The data get inserted in the database frequently and there must be no down time. What is the ideal way to back up these data. Is mysql Enterprise back up is a good option?

Comment: see tool called `mysqldump`

Comment: mysqldump can lock database for a long time with big data.

Comment: @BaBL86 Not necessarily, some switches can remove locking altogether (assuming InnoDB). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/104628/505722

Answer (score 1):

Use Percona with innoDB DB Engine. Percona toolkit include innobackupex utility, that can dump your base on the fly.

Or you can place your data folder on LVM partition and create snapshot. But it's slooooow...

Another way - replication. You can setup another mysql server as slave (for read only) and create backups from that second server. But it needs more money =)

Comment: thanks for your reply . Can i use Percona in windows? I heard that it is mainly for linux.

Comment: There is only one DBServer, that works normal in Windows: MSSQL Server. MySQL, Percona, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Firebird more powerful and more comfort and mostly developed for unix-like systems.