# PHP Warning: "MySQL server has gone away" after MySQL dump in macOS Terminal

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mysqli, dump

I am using a PHP script from CLI to download remote MySQL databases (gzip) and extract them directly to my MacBook's MySQL 5.7 (not MAMP) server.
It works fine, but as a side effect, my PHP apps (MAMP Pro) lose the MySQL connection in the middle of the CLI script with the warning

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in ...
```

This happens after roundabout a dozen databases (can't reproduce the exact amount). While the CLI script is running, the MySQL pane in System Preferences goes from green/running to red/stopped to again green/running after each CLI dump, which first does not conflict with the the PHP apps in the browser. But at some point the PHP apps obviously lose the connection.

I played around with my.cnf and set

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=128M
max_connections=1024
```

or other amounts, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

When I manually stop and start MySQL in System Preferences after the CLI script has finished, the PHP continues to work normal again.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Thanks so far, but it's still not fixed. So here’s the script in principal:

```
$tmpPath = '/tmp/'

For each of 30 databases with different size:

$dbName = database name

exec('ssh user@server.com "mysqldump --login-path=local --lock-tables=false '.$dbName.' | gzip" > '.$tmpPath.$dbName.'.sql.gz');
exec('gzip -q -dc '.$tmpPath.$dbName.'.sql.gz | mysql -u root -proot '.$dbName)
```

Like I said, the PHP **CLI script** in Terminal doesn't complain at all!
It’s my PHP **apps** (backend for Angular frontend apps) that somewhere in the middle of the 30 dumps stop working because of the mentioned error.

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';` and `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`

Comment: Meanwhile I discovered that MySQL in System Preferences goes red, so stops for half a second after each database dump and starts instantly again.

Comment: @RickJames Can you give me another hint what you mean with your comment? I have played around with the variable timeout settings but it didn't help.

Comment: Try pinging the mysql server occassionally with mysqli_ping()

Comment: @rndus2r I am running the PHP MySQL scripts all the time, until the connection is lost and the scripts fail. So checking the connection to the MySQL server all the time anyway.

Comment: How long does the script run for?

Comment: @user2113177 Are you sure about that? Once the PHP passes the dump to the mysql server, it actually has nothing to do, so it will lose the connection unless there is something to do. I assume you are not firing a query every second but just pass the whole dump to the server?

Comment: I had a similar problem 3 months ago. I did edit timeout(connect_timeout, wait_timeout and interactive_timeout) in the config file. In the code, I open and close connection all the time.

Comment: This warning doesn't mean the MySQL server stopped. It means the connection between your script and the MySQL server dropped for some reason. When both programs (the PHP script and the MySQL server) run on the same computer, the most probable cause of the situation is a timeout.

Comment: Another possible reason is a signal received by the PHP interpreter in a bad moment. Does your script launches children processes?

Comment: Could you post your dump script or an excerpt of it?

Comment: You updated the question but it's not clear at all. It seems the PHP script launches external processes that do the MySQL stuff. But on top of the question you ask about a PHP Warning regarding `mysqli::__connect()`. Does the script connect to the MySQL server **and** also launches external commands?

Comment: @user2113177 I asked twice for clarifications. Are you sure you want to solve the issue?

Comment: @axiac I have updated my question multiple times and replied to comments. So yes, I still want to solve this issue.

Comment: @Cuchu Can you please post your timeout settings?

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem and fixed by just adding max_connections = 1024 in mysql.conf

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, and used this which reconnects if the connection goes away:

```
<?php

use Exception;
use PDO;
use Our\Package\Common\Config\DbCredentials;

class DbConnectionManager
{
    private $credentials;

    /** @var PDO $connection */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * DbConnectionManager constructor.
     * @param DbCredentials $credentials
     */
    public function __construct(DbCredentials $credentials)
    {
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
        $this->reconnect();
    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public function getConnection()
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected()) {
            $this->reconnect();
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isConnected()
    {
        try {
            return $this->connection->query('SELECT 1 + 1;');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Reinitialise the connection to MySQL
     */
    private function reconnect()
    {
        $dsn = $this->credentials->getDriver()
            .':host='.$this->credentials->getHost()
            .';port='.$this->credentials->getPort()
            .';dbname='.$this->credentials->getDbName()
        ;
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $this->credentials->getUser(), $this->credentials->getPassword(), array(
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 28800,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        ));
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
}
```

You can tweak this. The DBCredentials class is just a plain PHP class with getters & setters for driver, hostname, user, password, db name, you could change it to just take arguments as strings if you like.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that
>   is incorrect or too large. If mysqld gets a packet that is **too large**.
>   or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the
>   client and closes the connection.

To avoid this problem ,You must ensure that max_allowed_packet is set bigger in the mysqld server than in the client and that all clients uses the same value for max_allowed_packet.
And Remember to restart your server after that !!!!

Comment: Please add links to the source of your quote/reference (is the yellow blockquote text copied from somewhere?).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a mysqldump you lock the tables. I think that is the main problem and that is why your applications is getting that error. Use this options:

```
--lock-tables, -l

Lock all tables before dumping them. The tables are locked with READ
LOCAL to allow concurrent inserts in the case of MyISAM tables. For
transactional tables such as InnoDB and BDB, --single-transaction is
a much better option, because it does not need to lock the tables at
all.
```

The original answer here:

> [Run MySQLDump without Locking Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables)

And try user some "sleep" between dump commands.

Comment: As far as I understand does `--lock-tables` only prevent that the live (source) database is not locked while dumping. But locally I don't use `mysqldump` but `gzip` unzips directly to mysql using `gzip -q -dc '.$tmpPath.$dbName.'.sql.gz | mysql -u root -proot '.$dbName`

Comment: Aww. Sorry. You local database crashes. I thought the server crashes. In that case try the "sleep" option, to get the indexing done in local when you import, and  try wait_timeout=30000